# Sharing a connection pool for all Rails uses of Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, connection-pooling, actioncable, connection-pool

**Summary**: I'm using a single Redis instance for the Rails cache, actioncable and (non-cache) use in my rails code.  Should all these uses share a single connection pool and if so how can I config this to make it happen since there seem to be totally different ways to setup the pooling for each?

---

---

Details follow since people seem to like to see them.

I'm using redis as the adapter for rails cache using the following config.

```
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, {
    url: "redis://XXX.net:6379/0",
    pool_size: ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 },
    password: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:redis, :password),
    expires_in: 24.hours,
    pool_timeout: 5
  }
```

I've set the expires_in option so that I can set the option in my redis config to evict keys with expiration set so I can use the same redis instance for both cache and non-cache data.  Now, I want to also access REDIS directly for non-cache related tasks via something like the example config below

```
pool_size = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS", 5)
redis_pool = ConnectionPool.new(size: pool_size) do
  Redis.new(
    url: "redis://XXX.net:6379/0",
  )
end
```

But I'm not sure if that is correct.  Shouldn't I be sharing a connection pool between the cache_store connections and the other connections to Redis?  If so, how can I do this?

To complicate matters further I'm also using Redis for actioncable via a config like

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://XXX.net:6379/0" } %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:redis, :password) %>
```

I've seen suggestions that actioncable will automatically handle connection pooling with Redis if I'm using the connection_pool gem (is this right?) but I feel like all these connections should be drawing from the same pool.  If so how can I make that happen?